# OSError: [Errno 5] EIO : When using 2 of the same sensors with same address on different I2C channels

Tags: micropython, errno, eoserror

I'm using a Cytron Maker Pi RP2040
Micropython

The sensors are [VL53L1X](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3967) from Adafruit

Sensor0 is connected to (SDA1)-GPIO26, (SCL1)-GPIO27
Sensor1 is connected to (SDA0)-GPIO16, (SCL0)-GPIO17

[I found this in Github](https://github.com/drakxtwo/vl53l1x_pico) and I'm using the same library as them. [The library in question](https://github.com/openmv/openmv/blob/master/scripts/libraries/vl53l1x.py)

I am fairly new to this but I've managed to make one of the sensor work at a time. But whenever I try to use 2 the second one gives me **OSError: [Errno 5] EIO** I made sure both are in different channels.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5COdK.png)

This is my set of funtions

```
class distance:

    def true_front(channel):
        global front_distance
        i2c = I2C(channel)
        distance = VL53L1X(i2c)
        front_distance = distance.read()
        print(str(front_distance) + "mm")
        sleep_ms(50)

    def true_rear(channel):
        global rear_distance
        i2c = I2C(channel)
        distance = VL53L1X(i2c)
        rear_distance = distance.read()
        print(str(rear_distance) + "mm")
        sleep_ms(50)
```

And this is how I executed them

```
while True:
    distance.true_front(0)
    sleep(1)
    distance.true_rear(1)
```

I looked into the library to see if there was a way to redo the handshake process everytime I call the funtions, but since this is still new to me I didn't manage to spot the solution.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what's going wrong but I would not reinitialise the I2C objects every time you want to read from them. Since you are using a class, try creating the i2c and VL53L1X objects in the class's `__init__` method and storing them as class attributes, e.g. `self.i2c = I2C(channel)` and so on. See if you can read repeated values from one sensor like this and then try reading from the second one.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get my hand on the board again, thanks a lot!